# ¿Como contar nombres de registros dinamicos en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT      ROOM_TYPE.type
FROM        ROOM_TYPE
INNER JOIN  ROOM
ON          ROOM.id_room_type = ROOM_TYPE.id
```

que me arroja el siguiente resultado

```
|  TYPE   |
----------
|sencilla |
 ---------
|sencilla |
 --------- 
|sencilla |
 ---------
|doble    |
 --------- 
|doble    |
 ---------
```

Lo que deseo es que me cuente el numero de apariciones de esas palabras
sabiendo que pueden ser en algun momento un distinto nombre o que se agregue un nuevo nombre a la tabla

Como por ejemplo

```
Total_sencilla | Total_doble |
--------------  ------------
     3         |      2      |
```

o tambien cuando sea otro nombre

```
Total_n_diferente_1   | Total_n_diferente_2 |Total_n_diferente_2 |       
---------------------   -------------------  -------------------
       7              |        9            |          12        |
```

A lo que me refiero que no este hardcodeado o estatico el nombre en la consulta

Estas son mis tablas

Tabla ROOM

```
ROOM
------------
id int
------------
id_room_type int
```

Tabla ROOM_TYPE

```
 ROOM_TYPE
 ------------
 id int
 ------------
 type varchar(50)
```

Comment: eso es una tabla pivotante.. pero para que? si es para solucionar un problema de Vista, ya te digo que no deberias hacerlo asi.. si es solo para verlo en un manejador de DB, se puede hacer.

Comment: si añado a la consulta 
SELECT      COUNT(ROOM_TYPE.type)  y  GROUP BY ROOM_TYPE.type  me cuenta las apariciones pero no me dice a que tipo pertenecen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

saludos puedes usar el **groupBy** y el **count**

**ejemplo:**

```
SELECT nombre_producto, count(1) as Total
FROM productos
GROUP BY nombre_producto
```

Te dejo el link con mas informacion de count :
[count mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html)

Comment: genial muchas gracias

Comment: No entiendo como esto resuelve la pregunta, porque mas alla que el group by este bien, OP mostro las cosas en horizontal.. (no quiero desmerecer la respuesta, es mas una queja a OP) @gokuvenz

Comment: SELECT      ROOM_TYPE.type, COUNT(1) AS total
FROM        ROOM_TYPE
INNER JOIN  ROOM
ON          ROOM.id_room_type = ROOM_TYPE.id
GROUP BY ROOM_TYPE.type